# Software for after sales process optimization

Tags: open-source, php, crm, processes

We have a sales team of about 10 people that gets customer calls (oders, requests for quotes, etc.) by phone, by email oder by fax.

Today every customer request is printed out on paper and put in a sales-inbox. The next free sales person fetches the request at the bottom and fulfils the task. There is no management view, sales queue or sales / process tracking today.

We are looking for a software to optimize this process and make it transparent.

This "after sales system" should have some key features:

- Sales requests sent to sales-request@company.com should directly start a sales task
- Sales tasks should be started manually, too
- All annotations and customer communication should be stored in the system for later follow-ups (e.g. order processing)
- A sales task queue (dashboard) shows the status of the sales tasks

Our technical requirements are:

- We like to expand it in PHP by either using an API oder writing extensions (e.g. for creating an order in our ERP system)
- Open source software is preferred but not required
- We need to host this internally, so there is no way for a hosted solution (SAAS)

We cannot use our crm system for this process and don't want to introduce another full blown crm system.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at CiviCRM or Sugar CRM?  Both should meet your needs and tech requirements.  Sugar's UI is more geared to your type of business.  CiviCRM has awesome integration with Drupal/WordPress. I do know several organizations that use Civi/Sugar to feed their main CRM

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a sales force automation software, to make your sales team productive and organized at the same time. The automation of document flow and orders & invoices will positively affect  the time-management of your salespeople and will definitely make their activities transparent. For example, bpm’online sales https://www.bpmonline.com/sales delivers the tools for account and contact management of the highest quality. Basically, bpm’online sales takes care of end-to-end sales processes - from lead to order, and to ongoing account maintenance. Your sales reps will definitely benefit from such sales automation